# Display macro syntax as plain text

Tags: macros, confluence

I want to display macro as plain text, Let's say I am using {style} macro so I want {style} to be displayed as plain text and not evaluated to macro.

Currently I am achieving this by doing undo (ctrl + z) as soon as macro is evaluated. Is there any escape character by which I can display it as plain text.

Why I need to do it?: I am creating a help page for macros.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question contains the perfect answer. Here are the 2 options I know, with some explanation:

### Using inline code

Example: {toc}

To create that, do the following steps:

1. Start typing {toc}, Confluence expands that to macro "table of content".
2. Press immediately after that CTRL-Z (for undo), which will restore the text {toc}.
3. Highlight then the text, and select from the menu: "Monospace", so that it looks like code.

This will be rendered as [image]

### Using the code macro

1. Start typing {code and complete to macro code block.
2. Enter inside the code block the following code (no completion): {toc} // renders a table of content
3. Save your page.

This will rendered as [image]